Thim Elementor Kit Causing Pagination Issues on Courses/Product/Shop Pages
Link to the page: https://everest.mk/kursevi/
I am experiencing an issue with Thim Elementor Kit that seems to be affecting pagination on my WordPress site. Here’s a detailed explanation of the problem:
Issue Description:

When using pagination (e.g., on archive pages, blog posts, or product
listings), the navigation links either: Do not work at all (e.g.,
clicking a page link does nothing).

Redirect to the same page without loading the next set of results.

This problem occurs specifically when the Thim Elementor Kit plugin
is activated.

Deactivating the plugin restores the pagination functionality, but
this breaks the layouts built with the plugin.


What I Have Tried So Far:

Regenerating permalinks via Settings > Permalinks.

Clearing all cache (site cache, browser cache, CDN cache).

Ensuring all plugins, themes, and WordPress core are updated.

Deactivating all plugins except Thim Elementor Kit and Elementor.


Findings:

The issue occurs only when Thim Elementor Kit is active.
Pagination works fine with other plugins and themes when the Thim
Elementor Kit is deactivated.

Expected Behavior:

Pagination should work smoothly, allowing navigation between pages
without errors or reload issues.

Request for Help:

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Are there any known fixes or workarounds?

Could this be a conflict between Thim Elementor Kit and other
components, or is it a bug within the plugin itself?


